# Create a composite of two images in android overlaying a specific section

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have two images I wish to merge together into one, the image that will become the background is configured so that the section I wish to overlay the second image on is coloured.

Is there any way to dynamically generate a composite of two images overlaid over a specific section?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the images have a least a little bit of alpha, you will have to use the Canvas class to draw the bitmaps. [Here's a link to the method documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)